# SQL Server Management Studio Connect to Server List Editing

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm using SQLServer Management Studio (2005) and I have a fairly lengthy list of servers in there, and I'd like to get rid of some of them that are no longer in use, without having to set them all up again.

I know that the `C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Shell\mru.dat` can be deleted and this will remove ALL the entries, but is there anyway to just delete some of them?

(Coding info)
I looked at the file and it is a serialised blob from the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.ConnectionDlg.dll` (Class Personalization) in the Appplication directory, but all the methods are private. So I can't just create an instance of this and then call Remove on the entries.

**Update**
I have written an Article on CodeProject explaining How this can be achieved.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/AlterSQL2005MRU.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much hacking with Reflection I have solved this problem. I've managed to write a VERY ugly application which uses a reference to the above mentioned DLL, and then can go in and remove a particular entry from the list. If people are interested, I might post the program on CodeProject as a way to do it. Let me know via votes or comments.

Answer (score 1):

It really isn't possible, even in a hacky/unsupported sort of way. See the following blog entry and related Microsoft Connect bug report:

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/03/18/managing-the-mru-list-for-the-connect-to-server-dialog-in-ssms.aspx

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/424800/ssms-expose-connect-to-server-mru-list-to-users